# Timidity won't play on second sound card

Tags: sound, alsa, midi

I have a trouble with Timidity and playing midi files. I have two soundcards -- the first is on-board and I don't use it, because of "poor" quality output. The second is USB card Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 which have great sound and works great in all apps I need, but timidity.

I set the second card in sound configuration as default. But Timidity ignores it and plays only on the first card. I cannot found solution on Timidity's website nor with google. I tried to run timidity with "-Oj" and "-Od" parameters. The first prints only error, that timidity is compiled without jackd support. The second does not work too. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Know anyone a solution? Or better midi synthesizer?
Thank you for all responses

Comment: unplug the on-board card if you can, is your computer a laptop or PC?

Comment: PC, but the first card is integrated on motherboard :-(...